# Breaking the conservation law with relativistic doppler effect?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, speed-of-light, energy-conservation, doppler-effect

Imagine we have a red photon of $780\text{ nm}$.
Using this from [**wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_energy):
$${\displaystyle E={\frac {hc}{\lambda }}}$$
$${\displaystyle E(eV)={\frac {1.2398}{\mathrm {\lambda } ({\mu }m)}}}$$
$${\displaystyle E(eV)={\frac {1.2398}{\mathrm {0.780 } ({\mu }m)}}}$$
$${\displaystyle E(eV)=1.58}$$
So a red photon of $780\text{ nm}$ has $1.58\text{ eV}$ of energy.

So if we launch the photon to a solar panel (100% efficiency) it would give us $1.58\text{ eV}$.
But...

Now we push the solar panel and it's travelling at $v = 0.99\text{c}$.
Using the relativistic doppler effect the photon can "change" of color. (Idea from [xkcd](https://what-if.xkcd.com/14/)).
I can't found how to use the Relativistic Doppler Effect with wavelength instead of frequency so:
$$f = \frac{c}{\lambda}$$
$$f = \frac{299,792,458\text{ m/s}}{780\text{ nm}}$$
$$f = 384,349.30\text{ hertz} = 384.34\text{ KHz}$$
Using the formula:
$${\displaystyle f_{o}=f_{s}{\sqrt {\frac {1-v/c}{1+v/c}}}}$$
Where here $v = -296,794,533.42$.
$${\displaystyle f_{o}=384,349.30{\sqrt {\frac {1-\frac{-296,794,533.42}{299,792,458}}{1+\frac{-296,794,533.42}{299,792,458}}}}}$$
$${\displaystyle f_{o}= 384,349.30{\sqrt {\frac {1-(-0.99)}{1+(-0.99)}}}}$$
$${\displaystyle f_{o}= 384,349.30{\sqrt {\frac {1.99}{0.01}}}}$$
$${\displaystyle f_{o}= 384,349.30{\sqrt {199}}}$$
$${\displaystyle f_{o}= 384,349.30 \times 14.10}$$
$${\displaystyle f_{o}= 5,419,325.13} = 5.41\text{ MHz}$$
Or using all the decimals: ${\displaystyle f_{o}= 5,421,914.17 = 5,42 \text{ MHz}}$

Now converting frequency in wavelengh:
$$f = \frac{c}{\lambda}$$
$$\lambda = \frac{c}{f}$$
$$\lambda = \frac{299,792,458\text{ m/s}}{5,421,914.17}$$
$$\lambda = \frac{299,792,458\text{ m/s}}{5,421,914.17}$$
$$\lambda = 55.29 \text{ nm}$$

Now the photon is EUV ([Extreme ultraviolet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_ultraviolet)).

And using:
$${\displaystyle E(eV)={\frac {1.2398}{\mathrm {\lambda } ({\mu }m)}}}$$
$${\displaystyle E(eV)={\frac {1.2398}{\mathrm {0.05529 } ({\mu }m)}}}$$
$${\displaystyle E(eV)={\frac {1.2398}{\mathrm {0.05529 } ({\mu }m)}}}$$
$${\displaystyle E(eV)=22.43}$$

So if we throw the photon to a super-fast solar panel it would give us $22.43 \text{ eV}$? Can I produce infinite energy with a red laser and solar panel travelling really fast?
**How can this be possible? The solar panel would get more energy?**
Is possible break conservation law with this? Obviously it isn't possible, but why? My theory is that when the photon collide to the panel it slow down the solar panel by the same amount of energy produced, am I right?:
$${\displaystyle P_{\text{absorb}}={\frac {\langle S\rangle }{c}}={\frac {E_{f}}{c}}}$$
Where $E_{f} = 22.43 \times (1.602176487 \times 10^{-19})$.
So ${\displaystyle P_{\text{absorb}}=0.012 \text{ yN}}$, no?

I am not sure if this is necesary but, if the solar panel has a mass of $1 \text{ kg}$.
$$E(J) = 1 \text{ kg} \times 296,794,533.42 \text{ m/s}$$
$$E(J) = 296,794,533.42 = 296,79 \text{ MJ}$$
or $296,794,533.42 * (6.2415 \times 10^{18}) = 1,852,443,080,340,930,000,000,000,000 \text{ eV} = 1,852 \text{ PeV}$

The photon would reduce the solar panel $0.012 \text{ ym/s}$ and it would need $0.012 \text { yN} = 0.012 \text { yJ}$ to speed up again.
$E(eV) = 0.000000000000000000000000012 * (6.2415 * 10^{18}) = 7.48 \text{ eV}$. And $7.48 + 1.58 = 9.06 < 22.43$, What I am missing?

Comment: Momentum has to be conserved so the momentum of the photon will slow the panel. Thermodynamically, everything should balance, even if you ignore the 100% efficient solar panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Energy is not conserved between reference frames. In the frame of the photon emitter, they only ever emitted a $1.59~\mathrm{eV}$ photon and the solar panel only absorbed a 1.59 eV photon. In the solar panels frame of reference, the emitter gave off a 22.43 eV photon and the solar panel absorbed a $22.43~\mathrm{eV}$ photon.

What the emitter sees is the solar panel absorb a $1.59~\mathrm{eV}$ photon and have it's momentum reduce by $1.59~\mathrm{eV/c}$. An observer travelling with the solar panel would see a $22.43~\mathrm{eV}$ photon strike the stationary panel and the panel increase its momentum by $22.43~\mathrm{eV/c}$ in the direction the photon was originally traveling.

How much energy you can collect from the solar panel depends entirely on how that solar panel sends you that energy. If, for example, it beams you back a photon of the energy that it received (making it effectively a mirror), that photon will undergo Doppler shift as well. This will of course, push the solar panel back even more, further reducing its kinetic energy. This can only be done until you've used up the kinetic energy of the solar panel. Another way you can collect energy is to store the energy in a battery attached to the solar panel and pick it up when you've made the solar panel stationary relative to you. In both cases, the amount of energy you can recover is less than the kinetic energy of the solar panel.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand a thing. So you said that the solar panel can absorb both measures of eV and that depends of the frame of reference, but if I use a multimeter or try to turn on a lamp, the lamp would receive $1.59 \text{ eV}$ or $22.43 \text{ eV}$ of energy?

Comment: Energy is not conserved between reference frames. What energy the solar panel absorbs s frame dependent. What the solar panels sees is different from what a different observer sees.

Answer (score 0):

Relativity is weird - but it doesn't violate conservation of energy.

If I accelerate the source towards me, then I have to give it additional energy in accordance with $$E^2 = p^2c^2 + m_0^2c^4$$

It is this extra energy that makes it possible to emit more energetic photons. The supply of these photons is not endless - every photon emitted lowers the energy of the emitter. And as the photon is emitted towards us, the source experiences a momentum "push" away from us.